# A one dimensional fractal like set with the same line width within a bounded area?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

Say that we have a line $\left(0,0.5\right)$. I want a process that can split that line and half and move that half a bit, and then take half of that half and moved it and so on, so that by the end all the pieces of the line would still be within the region $\left(0,1\right)$.

An example of such a series is to take half of the line and move it half its size:
$(0, 0.5)$

$(0, 0.25)$, $(0.375, 0.625)$

$(0, 0.25)$, $(0.375, 0.5)$, $(0.5625, 0.6875)$

1. Is there a name for such a series? (it is similar to a [cantor
   set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), but not quite)
2. How does one **formally** prove that this set will never reach 1, no matter how many splits we'll make?

Figure for 5 splits:

[image]

Comment: Oh, you construct a geometric series like that. I mis-interpreted your question. 

Your construction is clearly NOT a Cantor set, as it contains an interval.
It might still be considered to be a fractal though. In any case, your construction is simply two geometric series that determine the endpoints of the segments. Figuring out the rightmost one is straightforward 1-year calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a cantor-set. Also, by construction, the length is preserved in each step, so the Haussdorff dimension should be 1.

To prove that it is in $[0,1]$, depends on how you construct your sets.
If you impose the restriction that the segments in each step is within $(0,1)$, it should be trivial.

I assume you look for a general, fractal and self-similar construction.

I think you'll run into trouble by moving it half the size (it will self-intersect, I believe), but if you move it the full size, it is fine. This is easy via induction (make a picture).

EDIT: Here is a picture of my construction, each step on its own line.
The picture is a bit deceptive in the end, it really should be "gray" or something.

[image: fractal lines]

```
lines[y_, n_] := 
  Table[Line[{{k/2^n, y}, {(k + 1)/2^n, y}}], {k, 0, 2^n - 1, 2}];
Graphics[ Join @@ Table[lines[-k/20, k] , {k, 1, 9}]]
```

Comment: I created a picture of the set. Is there a reference I can use? (I'm not sure why I should call it a cantor-set)

Comment: Interval $(0,1/4)$ remains at every stage?  This is not a Cantor set.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: I was thinking you recursively perform the same operation on each individual line segment. In every step, the number of segments doubles, but they are only half as long.

Comment: Dear @PerAlexandersson - thank you for the answer. I like your construction, is there a way to prove (or reference) that this is a cantor set?

Comment: It is clear from the construction that the limit set will not contain an interval.